# What's wrong?: Find the infinite sum $S = 1 + \frac{3}{4} + \frac{7}{16} + \frac{15}{64} + \frac{31}{256} + \ldots$

Tags: geometric-series

The answer I got by hand is not the same to the one I found using a spreadsheet.

$\displaystyle S = 1 + \frac{3}{4} + \frac{7}{16} + \frac{15}{64} + \frac{31}{256} + \ldots$

---

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{4}S = \hspace{8.5pt} \frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{16} + \frac{7}{64} + \frac{15}{256} + \ldots$

$\displaystyle \frac{3}{4}S = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{16} + \ldots \qquad \leftarrow  S- \frac{1}{4}S$

For the Infinite Sum on the RHS $\displaystyle \left(S = \frac{a}{1-r}\right)$:

$\displaystyle a = 1$

$\displaystyle r = \frac{1}{2}$

Then

$\displaystyle \frac{3}{4}S = \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}}$

$\displaystyle \frac{3}{4}S = 2$

$\displaystyle S = \frac{8}{3}$

Using Excel the answer is $\displaystyle \frac{5}{3}$, but I don't know where is the issue.

Thanks!!

Comment: try to learn some python, is better than excel!

Comment: Why is $\frac34 S $ is what you wrote up there,?

Comment: @Atvin I subtracted the series $\frac{1}{4}S$ from $S$. Thus $S - \frac{1}{4}S = \frac{3}{4}S$.

Comment: @LuisFelipeVillavicencioLopez for this problem, both will work same and hence suggestion is not useful.

Comment: I am not sure that $\frac34 S$ will be the complete $1+\frac12+...$ series, I don't find $\frac14$

Comment: It is highly likely that you forgot the first term $1$ in Excel.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because: it is about a problem with an Excel model of a mathematical problem. Debugging Excel spreadsheets is off-topic for MSR.

Comment: The terms are all positive and the sum of the first two is clearly greater than $\frac 53$. Basic reality checks always come in handy. I think @YvesDaoust is very likely right.

Comment: Excel can't do infinite summation. Debugging your representation of an infinite series in Excel is not in the scope of MSE. You should be able to calculate the first few partial sums by hand to resolve the inconsistency.

Comment: @RobArthan Take it easy. I just did the thing up to 50 terms (in Excel is a good approximation to infinity). As Yves Daoust says, I forgot to add the first term: $1$.

Comment: In general, I would strongly advise against using ANY language  to evaluate infinite series except for WolframAlpha, Mathematica, Matlab, etc which have support for it. The reason is because simply adding the terms can result in huge errors if convergence is slow. To see a good example of how things can go wrong, try 'evaluate' the harmonic series.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: Notice that
$$
S = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{2^{i+1}-1}{2^{2i}}
$$
and distribute.

Answer (score 2):

We can pattern match this to a difference of geometric series. The sum in question is $$\begin{align} 1 + \frac{3}{4} + \frac{7}{16} + \frac{15}{64} + \frac{31}{256}  = 1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2^{k+1}-1}{4^{k}} \\ =  1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2^{k+1}}{4^{k}}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{4^{k}}\end{align}$$ Now use geometric series...

Comment: Better to write answer without ambiguity...+1

Answer (score 2):

Your answer seems to be correct. We see that Excel's answer is wrong by adding just the first 2 terms in the series, $1, \frac 34$ and we see that $1.75>1.66..$, so we can see that Excel's answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

At first, note that $S=\dfrac{2^1-1}{4^{1-1}} + \dfrac{2^2-1}{4^{2-1}}+ \dfrac{2^3-1}{4^{3-1}}+\dfrac{2^4-1}{4^{4-1}} + \dfrac{2^5-1}{4^{5-1}}+\ldots $

> **So**: $$S=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{2^k-1}{4^{k-1}}?$$
>
> $$S=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{2^k}{4^{k-1}}-\dfrac{1}{4^{k-1}}$$
> $$S=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{4}{2^k}-\dfrac{1}{4^{k-1}}$$
> And you can go on since here.

Comment: That sum is not correct

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{2^k-1}{2^{k+1}}=1/4+3/8+\dots$

Comment: Hey downvoter man, I improve my answer 2 hours ago, you are so fast for somethings but slow for others.

Answer (score 0):

When you write "Using Excel the answer is $\frac{5}{3}$", I think what you mean is that you have constructed a model of the problem in Excel that suggests the answer is $\frac{5}{3}$. Your Excel model of the problem is wrong (as calculation by hand of the first few terms of of the sum shows). So the issue is in your Excel model. Debugging your Excel model is off topic for MSE.